# Convert point to rectangle polygon with width x km and height y km in sf R

Tags: r, r-sf

I can convert a point to a square or circle polygon using `st_buffer(point, dist = 1, endCapStyle = "SQUARE")`

But, how to convert a point to a rectangle polygon with width x km and height y km in sf R?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, although you must be careful with the units of your projection. Since you didn't provide further data, I used a custom example. Basically, the answer is to create a `bbox` around your point with the desired dimensions:

```r
library(sf)
#> Warning: package 'sf' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))[1,]
#> Reading layer `nc' from data source `C:\Users\q31407\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\sf\shape\nc.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> epsg (SRID):    4267
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs

# Project to get coods in "m", example 3857, could be any 
nc <- st_geometry(st_transform(nc,3857))
point <- st_centroid(nc)

point
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -9072327 ymin: 4360181 xmax: -9072327 ymax: 4360181
#> epsg (SRID):    3857
#> proj4string:    +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
#> POINT (-9072327 4360181)

#Important: coordinates in m, adjust the units on function
# Helper funct
rect_around_point <- function(x,xsize,ysize){
  bbox <- st_bbox(x)
  bbox <- bbox +c(xsize/2,ysize/2,-xsize/2,-ysize/2)
  return(st_as_sfc(bbox))
}

rect <- rect_around_point(point,10000,20000)
rect
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -9077327 ymin: 4350181 xmax: -9067327 ymax: 4370181
#> epsg (SRID):    3857
#> proj4string:    +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
#> POLYGON ((-9067327 4370181, -9077327 4370181, -...

plot(rect, axes=TRUE)
plot(point, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: How to use these functions if I have multiple points of sf data frame?

Comment: I suggest you modify your question including an example dataset or `sfc`. Answering your comment, you can loop over the rows and create a `sfc` binding the rectangles. This example may give you some hints https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/351644/142200