# Find 8 neighbors of a point in a raster in R?

Tags: r, raster

If I have a raster like this:

```
 library(raster)
 r1 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
 r1[] <- runif(ncell(r1))
 r1[] = 1:ncell(r1)
 x=c(-6)            
 y=c(-67)
```

I can extract values that correspond to this point as:

```
values = extract(r1, SpatialPoints(cbind(y,x),CRS("+init=EPSG:4326")))
```

However, this extracts the closest pixel to the coordinates of this point.
I need to extract the 9 closest pixels (8 neighbors to the pixel extracted)to this point. Any idea?

Comment: the easiest way (imo) is to create a buffer of length 1 around your center point and then intersect it with the original raster. i have little experience with sp but with the sf package this is possible

Comment: Thanks, can you propose something please?

Comment: The `raster::extract` function takes a `buffer=` argument for cases like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `adjacent` method for that.

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) = 1:ncell(r)
xy <- cbind(-67, -6)
```

Solution

```
cells <- cellFromXY(r, xy)
adj <- adjacent(r, cells, 8, include=TRUE)

r[adj[,2]]
# [1] 54 43 53 63 45 55 65 44 64
```

This returns the value for the cells (because `include=TRUE`) and their 8 neighbors

Answer (score 0):

your horizontal data is twice as far away as your vertical data. for this reason instead of buffering a circle around your center point you need a 2:1 rectangle. i was to lazy to write one so i found an ad hoc function created by dieghernan in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60769423/convert-point-to-rectangle-polygon-with-width-x-km-and-height-y-km-in-sf-r)

after converting your point into an sf object i put the rectangle around it and intersected it with the raster.

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)

r1 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r1[] <- runif(ncell(r1))
r1[] = 1:ncell(r1)
x=c(-6)            
y=c(-67)

pt <- st_point(x = c(x,y))

r2 <- cbind.data.frame(values, raster::coordinates(r1)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"))

r_buff <- st_buffer(pt, 50)

## function by @dieghernan
rect_around_point <- function(x,xsize,ysize){
  bbox <- st_bbox(x)
  bbox <- bbox +c(xsize/2,ysize/2,-xsize/2,-ysize/2)
  return(st_as_sfc(bbox))
}

rect <- rect_around_point(pt, 100, 50)

result <- st_intersection(r2, rect) %>% 
  st_sf()

result

Simple feature collection with 9 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -54 ymin: -81 xmax: 18 ymax: -45
CRS:           NA
   values        geometry
74     74 POINT (-54 -45)
75     75 POINT (-18 -45)
76     76  POINT (18 -45)
84     84 POINT (-54 -63)
85     85 POINT (-18 -63)
86     86  POINT (18 -63)
94     94 POINT (-54 -81)
95     95 POINT (-18 -81)
96     96  POINT (18 -81)
```